# Dynamic Html pages from Mysql with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working on a website with php and mysql and have some problems to generate web pages URL from database rows.

I have only 3 page connection.php (mysql connection) index.php (where show al products/contents thumbnails with button with product details URL) and details.php where i want show info for single product.

from index.php i add a link to redirect to details.php page with this:

`<a href="details.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>"`

it's work but Big problem is in details.php because the script don't show a single products details, but show all products, please someone can help me? Thank you

**index.php** code

```
......other html code......
<div class="row">
<?php

require_once 'connection.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM campi_name";
$stmt = $DBcon->prepare( $query );
$stmt->execute();
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
?>


<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
<div class="thumbnail">
<img src="<?php echo $row['Thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['Title']; ?    >">
 <div class="caption">
 <h4><?php echo substr($row['Title'], 0, 30); ?></h4>
 <p><?php echo $row['Brand']; ?></p>
 <?php echo $row['ID']; ?>
 <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Cofronta</a> <a href="dettagli.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" role="button">Dettagli</a></p>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>


 <?php
 }
 ?>
 ......other html code......
```

**connection.php** code

```
$DBhost = "localhost";
$DBuser = "root";
$DBpass = "";
$DBname = "prodotti";



try {
$DBcon = new PDO("mysql:host=$DBhost;dbname=$DBname",$DBuser,$DBpass);
$DBcon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $ex){
die($ex->getMessage());
}

?>
```

**details.php** code

```
......other html code......
<div class="container">


<div class="row">

<?php

require_once 'connection.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM campi_name";
$stmt = $DBcon->prepare( $query );
$stmt->execute();
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
?>


<div class="col-sm-4 stylerow">            
<a href="<?php echo $row['AffiliateLink']; ?>" class="thumbnail">
<img src="<?php echo $row['Thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['Title']; ?  >">
</a>

</div>


<div class="col-sm-8 stylerow">
<h2><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></h2>
<p><?php echo $row['Brand']; ?></p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Amazon</button>
</div>

</div>

</div><!-- /.container -->
......other html code......
```

Comment: Look at `SELECT * FROM campi_name`, you need to tell it what you want. `SELECT * FROM campi_name where id = ?` then bind the GET `ID`. `$stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']));`

Comment: you will need to use the GET on details.php just like chris85 said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add 
$id=$_GET['id'];

edit following line in your code

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM campi_name";
```

To

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM campi_name where id="'.$id.'" ";
```

Comment: @Raman your code is prone to sql injection attack `$id` should be binded