# Show 5 random item and 5 item by brand mysql php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello please someone can help me with this code?  I think there i can remove * and GET id.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<h1>Sidebar</h1>
 <?php

    require_once 'connessione.php';
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM campi_name where id='$id'";
    $stmt = $DBcon->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    ?>


<div class="media">
<div class="media-left">
<a href="#">
<img class="media-object" src="..." alt="...">
</a>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

How can i show only item (from db) related to the **Brand** row from table **campi_name**?

and with code like that how i can show 5 random item from **campi_name**?

Thank you!

Comment: 5 random items from campi_name table `SELECT * FROM campi_name ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5`

Comment: `fetch();` is used to fetch a single result, use fetchall() instead : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075954/pdo-fetch-fetchall

Comment: for the sql logic we would need to know more column names to know how to `JOIN` your data

Comment: And u are using PDO prepared wrong way

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile have you a sample of a best way to do?

Comment: @happymacarts column name: ASIN, Brand, Title, Rating, Price, Thumbnail, AffiateLink, SalesRank, TechPeso, TechDimensioni, TechColore, TechDispositivi, TechMateriale

Comment: @Stew can u re explain what u wanna do?

Comment: @Masivuye Cokile i try, but only with a preview of the site, actually i work on it locally

Answer (score 0):

For the first question you can use

```
$query = "SELECT Brand FROM campi_name WHERE id='" . $id . "'";
```

I'm not sure because I haven't understand what you are asking. Do you want to select only `Brand` column or what? Do you want to select just the row that content some letters?

For the second question use

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM campi_name ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5"
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply, i want show item with the same brand, in db i have a row with products brand
ID,TITLE,BRAND,PRICE,etc,ectc

Comment: So `$query = "SELECT * FROM campi_name WHERE Brand='" . your brand variable . "'";`

Comment: Example: If you want to select all rows where Brand="Coca cola" then `$brand = "Coca cola"; $query = "SELECT * FROM campi_name WHERE Brand='" . $brand . "'";` It will select all rows of the product of the brand "Coca cola" With this code you need to set `$brand` like the brand thet you want

Comment: sorry maybe I badly explained myself, in my script i have index.php and details.php when click on a item on index.php an user will redirect to details.php page where he can see item details, here how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616083/dynamic-html-pages-from-mysql-with-php

In details.php i placed a sidebar where i want show random products/item and 5 products from the same brand of products/item actually showing in the page, there a sample: http://comparewear.com/smartwatches/pebble-time/ check sidebar

hope I explained myself, thank you!

Comment: I donwvoted you for using this query `$query = "SELECT Brand FROM campi_name WHERE id='" . $id . "'";` on a prepared statement